# how to change path with Link, NavLink, or Redirect (not full reload) in input navbar react

Tags: reactjs

I want change path to /search/:username from searchbar in NavBar component but when I used navlink, link, and redirect, my navbar is disappear. I only can change path with window.location but I just want reload data.

This is my app.js

```
      <div>
        <NavBar user={user} />
        <div className="container not-navbar">
          <Switch>
            <Route
              path="/profile/:username?"
              render={props => <Profile {...props} user={user} />}
            />
            {/* <Route
              path="/feed"
              render={props => <Feed {...props} user={user} />}
            /> */}
            <Route path="/search/:username" exact component={SearchPerson} />
            <Route path="/login" exact component={Login} />
            <Route path="/logout" exact component={Logout} />
            <Route path="/register" exact component={Register} />
            <Route path="/not-found" component={NotFound} />
            <Route path="/" exact component={Intro} />
            <Redirect to="/not-found" />
          </Switch>
        </div>
      </div>
```

I don't know to change path in navbar, because props in my navbar not available Route props. 
If you know change path not full reload without Link, Redirect or Navlink, please tell me.

My function

```
onSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.setState({ redirect: true });
  };



render() {
    const { user } = this.props;
    if (this.state.redirect) {
      return <Link to={`/search/${this.state.searchInput}`} />;
    }
```

Comment: the second code is your NavBar?

Comment: yes, in navbar component.

Answer (score 1):

You Can Simply Use Redirect to change pages

```
  onSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.setState({ redirect: true });
  };
  render() {
    const { user } = this.props;
    if (this.state.redirect) {
      return <Redirect to={`/search/${this.state.searchInput}`} />;
    }
```

Comment: is this help you ?

Comment: I already used this code, but my NavBar disappear after submit, because NavBar not include Router, I think this can solving with Ref to a button. Where the button Link target to path.